# Itext and Pdfbox Rotation settings compatibility issues

Tags: java, pdf, itext, pdf-generation, pdfbox

i have a PDF which is generated by itext and when i'm trying to load it using pdfbox it is getting loaded in landscape mode i.e width and height are interchanged (normally width and height of a PDF which is in portrait mode is 595 and 842(in points) respectively.) but when viewed it is in portrait mode.

it looks like 90 degrees is the portrait value for pdf generated by itext as for pdfbox is 0 degrees. i tried rotating the pdf but still no luck
any help would be appreciated.

UPDATED :

i tried adding signature field to this pdf but image is not being shown, i guess i'm not giving the correct cooordinates here . what should i do here ?

```
void addImageOnlySignatureField(PDDocument pdDocument, PDPage pdPage, PDRectangle rectangle, PDSignature signature) throws IOException {
    PDAcroForm acroForm = pdDocument.getDocumentCatalog().getAcroForm();
    List<PDField> acroFormFields = acroForm.getFields();

    PDSignatureField signatureField = new PDSignatureField(acroForm);
    signatureField.setValue(signature);
    PDAnnotationWidget widget = signatureField.getWidgets().get(0);
    acroFormFields.add(signatureField);

    widget.setRectangle(rectangle);
    widget.setPage(pdPage);

    // from PDVisualSigBuilder.createHolderForm()
    PDStream stream = new PDStream(pdDocument);
    PDFormXObject form = new PDFormXObject(stream);
    PDResources res = new PDResources();
    form.setResources(res);
    form.setFormType(1);
    PDRectangle bbox = new PDRectangle(rectangle.getWidth(), rectangle.getHeight());

    form.setBBox(bbox);

    // from PDVisualSigBuilder.createAppearanceDictionary()
    PDAppearanceDictionary appearance = new PDAppearanceDictionary();
    appearance.getCOSObject().setDirect(true);
    PDAppearanceStream appearanceStream = new PDAppearanceStream(form.getCOSObject());
    appearance.setNormalAppearance(appearanceStream);
    widget.setAppearance(appearance);

    try (   PDPageContentStream cs = new PDPageContentStream(pdDocument, appearanceStream);
            InputStream imageResource = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/mkl/testarea/pdfbox2/content/Willi-1.jpg") )
    {
        cs.saveGraphicsState();
        Matrix m = new Matrix();
        m.rotate(90);
        cs.transform(m);
        PDImageXObject pdImage = PDImageXObject.createFromByteArray(pdDocument, ByteStreams.toByteArray(imageResource), "Willi");
        cs.addComment("This is a comment");
        cs.drawImage(pdImage, 0, 0, rectangle.getWidth(), rectangle.getHeight());
        cs.restoreGraphicsState();

    }

    pdPage.getAnnotations().add(widget);
    
    COSDictionary pageTreeObject = pdPage.getCOSObject(); 
    while (pageTreeObject != null) {
        pageTreeObject.setNeedToBeUpdated(true);
        pageTreeObject = (COSDictionary) pageTreeObject.getDictionaryObject(COSName.PARENT);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please share the PDF file and tell how you viewed the PDF file.

Comment: I assume that in one case the OP uses a portrait media box and page rotation and in the other case a landscape media box. Either option is possible with either library.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr 
[this is the pdf](https://drive.google.com/file/d/19JTn1S8DBHVUIMegQOdNMw0q7acHU8Kp/view?usp=sharing)

i viewed it in adobe reader, and when i'm using the pdf for adding text fields i noticed that all the fields are being placed vertically because of it's behaviour in pdfbox. i adjusted the field placements for now. but i just wanted to understand , is this behaviour expected ? as i'm new to pdfbox i want to understand these things

Comment: @mkl [github](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-pdfbox2/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/pdfbox2/sign/CreateMultipleVisualizations.java)

the code you've provided for adding Image to Signature Field  (addImageOnlySignatureField) how should i adjust it for this pdf?

Comment: *"how should i adjust it for this pdf?"* - In `addImageOnlySignatureField` the appearance is generated in the `try (   PDPageContentStream cs = ...)` block. Add a `cs.transform` instruction at the start of that block that counters the page rotation.

Comment: The PDF displays in Adobe Reader exactly like in PDFBox: in portrait mode. Your page has a 90° rotation which makes everything more difficult when adding content. For annotations you can use the rotation in the PDAppearanceCharacteristicsDictionary to compensate.

Comment: thanks @TilmanHausherr i've tried it for textfields it is working

Comment: @mkl i've updated the code in my post can you please point out what am i doing wrong there ? should i use the x and y axis coordinates from the rectangle that is used during field placement ?

Comment: *"i've updated the code in my post can you please point out what am i doing wrong there ?"* - see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned in comments, you have to counter the page rotation when generating the signature appearance. And when rotating the appearance to do so, one must not forget that a pure rotation also rotates the content to be out of the bounding box of the appearance. Thus, one also has to translate.

Thus, the original (page rotation un-aware) code

```
try (   PDPageContentStream cs = new PDPageContentStream(pdDocument, appearanceStream);
        InputStream imageResource = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/mkl/testarea/pdfbox2/content/Willi-1.jpg") )
{
    PDImageXObject pdImage = PDImageXObject.createFromByteArray(pdDocument, ByteStreams.toByteArray(imageResource), "Willi");
    cs.addComment("This is a comment");
    cs.drawImage(pdImage, 0, 0, rectangle.getWidth(), rectangle.getHeight());
}
```

*([CreateMultipleVisualizations](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-pdfbox2/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/pdfbox2/sign/CreateMultipleVisualizations.java#L320) helper method `addImageOnlySignatureField`)*

has to be changed into something like this:

```
try (   PDPageContentStream cs = new PDPageContentStream(pdDocument, appearanceStream);
        InputStream imageResource = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/mkl/testarea/pdfbox2/content/Willi-1.jpg") )
{
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    boolean switchLengths = false;
    switch (pdPage.getRotation() % 360) {
    case 90:
        matrix.translate(rectangle.getWidth(), 0);
        matrix.rotate(Math.PI/2);
        switchLengths = true;
        break;
    case 180: //untested
        matrix.translate(rectangle.getWidth(), rectangle.getHeight());
        matrix.rotate(Math.PI);
        break;
    case 270: //untested
        matrix.translate(0, rectangle.getHeight());
        matrix.rotate(-Math.PI/2);
        switchLengths = true;
        break;
    }
    cs.transform(matrix);

    PDImageXObject pdImage = PDImageXObject.createFromByteArray(pdDocument, ByteStreams.toByteArray(imageResource), "Willi");
    cs.addComment("This is a comment");
    if (switchLengths)
        cs.drawImage(pdImage, 0, 0, rectangle.getHeight(), rectangle.getWidth());
    else
        cs.drawImage(pdImage, 0, 0, rectangle.getWidth(), rectangle.getHeight());
}
```

*([CreateMultipleVisualizations](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-pdfbox2/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/pdfbox2/sign/CreateMultipleVisualizations.java#L417-L447) helper method `addRotationAwareImageOnlySignatureField`)*

Comment: @Ghost *"it worked"* - Great! Beware, though, I only tested the 90° case (with your example file). The code for 180° and 270° looks correct but it's not tested.